# How to format a link within a code block

Tags: support, code-formatting, markdown, hyperlinks

I tried to edit one of my posts by adding a comment within a code block which contains a link.

Like so:

```css
.example { 
        text-decoration: underline;
        -moz-text-decoration-color: red;  /* [vendor prefix not required as of V36][1] */
        text-decoration-color: red;
}

  [1]: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox/Releases/36#css
```

Can this be formatted correctly somehow or must I add the link after the code block?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

#### Sure, here you go:

I tried to edit one of my posts by adding a comment within a code block which contains a link. Like so:

```css
.example { 
        text-decoration: underline;
        -moz-text-decoration-color: red;  /* vendor prefix not required as of V36 */
        text-decoration-color: red;
}
```

---

Whether that's a good idea and worth the trouble? I wouldn't bother nearly always. Anyway, here's the "markdown"-source:

```
I tried to edit one of my posts by adding a comment within a code block which contains a link. Like so:

<!-- language: lang-css -->

<pre><code>.example { 
        text-decoration: underline;
        -moz-text-decoration-color: red;  /* <a href="https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox/Releases/36#css">vendor prefix not required as of V36</a> */
        text-decoration-color: red;
}</code></pre>
```

Comment: As this shows, it's not very common to have clickable links in source code. In this case I'd just mention it below the code.

Comment: Note links are underlined in meta but not in Stack Overflow, so it's hard to notice them. See [Underline links inside code blocks](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/321600/1529630)