# Underline links inside code blocks

Tags: feature-request, design, code-formatting, syntax-highlighting

Sometimes I use links inside code blocks, e.g.

```js
interface HTMLCollection {
  readonly attribute unsigned long length;
  getter Element? item(unsigned long index);
  getter Element? namedItem(DOMString name);
};
```

Here in meta links are underlined so it's easy to see them, but in main site [it looks like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36809002/4151918)

[image]

You can only discover the links if you hover them and notice the pointer cursor.

So I propose underlining links inside code blocks. Something like

```css
code a {
  text-decoration: underline dotted;
}
```

This will also affect inline code, which does not really need it because links have `color: #07C`, but might be good for coherence. Otherwise restrict the selector to `pre > code a`.

Comment: Links don't belong in code -- it's a distraction, and makes it harder to read the code. If you want to link to docs, you can do it outside the code block :)

Comment: @PetahChristian Note I only include links when I quote a specification, the specification has links, and the formatting of the spec is important. The example above is Web IDL code used by the DOM spec to define an interface, it's not supposed to be run by any program.

Comment: I have never ever had a situation where the links in a WebIDL definition in a Stack Overflow answer were important enough in context that I absolutely had to include them like that.

Comment: Whether this feature gets implemented depends entirely on whether the <pre><code> method of marking up code blocks is supported in the first place. Note that "works" != "is supported".

Comment: @BoltClock They are not vital, but I think they are nice.

Comment: @Oriol In your [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36809002/4151918), you already linked to [HTMLCollection](https://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#htmlcollection), which itself *already* had links for the definition.  You've merely duplicated what the spec already provided. The additional links (in the code) may save the user one click, but  introduce more possibilities of link-rot.

Comment: @PetahChristian That's a good point. But I still think links in code blocks are not visible enough. In a certain point of view, this could even be considered a bug: syntax highlighter wraps text inside links in a span of some color, preventing the default `color: #07C` of links from being applied.