# Why is the last activity link not clearly displayed?

Tags: discussion, design

While I was on cs.stackexchange.com, I realised that the last activity date (above the 'related' section) was actually a link because it was blue ([example](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/63018/visual-programming-tools-why-don-t-they-work-with-the-ast-directly))

On the main site and meta, the css display this link in black so it's impossible to know it's a link. Shouldn't that be changed ?

[image]

Comment: Related, for the content of posts: [Can you please add underlines to hyperlinks?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326004/247702)