# Code formatted links are invisible on mobile

Tags: bug, code-formatting, user-interface, hyperlinks, mobile-web

On mobile, it's impossible to tell that there is a hyperlink in a post if the link text uses `code` formatting exclusively.

For exampe, [here:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67031976/874188)

[image: "fullname" is a link, the others not]

Could the CSS for mobile view please be updated to provide some sort of visual cue that something is a link? I seem to vaguely recall that these used to get an underline as well at some point in the past; or maybe the text color used to be blue or purple depending on whether you had visited the link or not.

My browser is Firefox on IOS but I see the same formatting problem in Safari and Chrome, too.

Comment: Related? https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321600/underline-links-inside-code-blocks (the question doesn't make any sense on mobile; perhaps it no longer makes sense in a desktop browser either after the migration to Commonmark?)

Comment: Related on SE: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/353663/hyperlinks-in-code-formatting-no-longer-follows-site-color