# Why can't we put links in code blocks and backtick-escaped sections?

Tags: feature-request, code-formatting

Say I just suggested some data type -- like this: `Array` -- or wrote a code block

```
Array a = [1, 2, 3]
```

Why can't I put a hyperlink in there somehow? Say the user who asked the question is a beginner and couldn't know about the specific thing I just wrote in my code. It would be useful to link to some tutorial page in the code instead of having to write something like

> [Here's](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06tc147t.aspx) the MSDN page on `switch` statements.

**after** the code. I know backticks are used to write something without it being formatted, but there still should be some way (that no language would ever use) to put links in code and escaped sections.

Comment: You can, but maybe you shouldn't: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/300633/2675154

Comment: A link's title text can include backtick-formatted portions. I link to reference docs when mentioning a class or function name all the time. E.g.: http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/6991f554-ec06-41b7-a435-de3416ea93c9/view-source

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually you can. You just have to use `<code>` and `<pre>` instead of the markdown syntax, which allows you to use plain HTML links:

```
<pre><code><a href="https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06tc147t.aspx">switch</a> (foo) {
    case 2: break; // <a href="http://example.com/">http://example.com/</a>
}</code></pre>
```

which renders as:

```c#
switch (foo) {
    case 2: break; // http://example.com/
}
```

Same with inline code:

```
<code><a href="https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06tc147t.aspx">switch</a> (foo) { }</code>
```

which results in `switch (foo) { }`.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know that! Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Note links are underlined in meta but not in Stack Overflow, so it's hard to notice them. See [Underline links inside code blocks](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/321600/1529630)

Comment: @Oriol This is a pick your poison scenario: if you leave out `<code>`, the links will be displayed in their usual colour, at the cost of automatic syntax highlighting.